# Should tmpfs be unmounted at system shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, unmounting, tmpfs

Assume I have a linux system with the following partitions mounted (beside root):

- proc on **/proc**

  devtmpfs on **/dev**

  devpts on **/dev/pts**

  tmpfs on **/dev/shm**

  sysfs on **/sys**

  tmpfs on **/var/run**

  tmpfs on **/tmp**

What should I do before halt (very last script executed, just before issuing the halt command)? Should I umount all these filesystems, leaving only /dev and /proc mounted? May leaving these filesystems mounted cause any problem? Is there a best practice about this?

UPDATE: I'm currently using sysvinit (latest) with own-written scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Debian, and likely its derivatives, the script which handles unmounts before halt/reboot is `/etc/init.d/umountfs`.

For me, the script does not `umount` any of the filesystems you have listed apart from `tmpfs`. The reason is given in the following comment:

```
# Make sure tmpfs file systems are umounted before turning off
# swap, to avoid running out of memory if the tmpfs filesystems
# use a lot of space.
```

Given the maturity of these scripts, I guess this is best practice, although it might be a good idea to investigate what other distros do.

It is also possible that the `halt`/`reboot` commands actually require some of the above mount to work (most likely `/proc`, but also `/sys` and `/dev`) and the command may fail without them.

#### Update

To add a little more on this, the next script called after `umountfs`, before the actual `halt` script itself is `umountroot`. Contrary to what the name suggests, the script actually remounts root readonly. Note the actual syntax for this:

```
mount    $MOUNT_FORCE_OPT -n -o remount,ro -t dummytype dummydev / 2>/dev/null \
  || mount $MOUNT_FORCE_OPT -n -o remount,ro              dummydev / 2>/dev/null \
  || mount $MOUNT_FORCE_OPT -n -o remount,ro                       /
```

Seemingly just doing a straight `mount -no remount,ro /` can fail if there are other mount points bound to root. See [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=339023) for a full discussion of this. The `MOUNT_FORCE_OPT` is only set for FreeBSD, so this is not necessary for Linux.

Comment: This just raises another question. Why do they bother turning off swap?